# Discrepancy in PI Controller Outputs for voltage control and current control for droop control strategy in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, simulink

**Issue:**
I am implementing a PI controller for the dq-transformation of a three-phase system in MATLAB. The goal is to control the q-axis voltage (iq_ref) and current (vq_inv) based on desired values. The system is simulated using a fixed-step solver in Simulink, and I am trying to replicate the results in MATLAB.
Problem Description:
I have implemented the PI controllers for Vq and Iq using the following equations:

```
% PI controller for Vq
error_vq(n) = Vq_ref(n) - V1q(n-1);
prop_vq = kpv * error_vq(n);
int_vq(n) = kiv * (Ts/2) * (error_vq(n) + error_vq(n-1)) + int_vq(n-1);
int_vq(n-1) = int_vq(n);
error_vq(n-1) = error_vq(n);
iq_ref(n) = prop_vq + int_vq(n) + (wc * V1d(n));

% PI controller for Iq
error_iq(n) = iq_ref(n) - I1q(n-1);
prop_iq = kpi * error_iq(n);
int_iq(n) = kii * (Ts/2) * (error_iq(n) + error_iq(n-1)) + int_iq(n-1);
int_iq(n-1) = int_iq(n);
error_iq(n-1) = error_iq(n);
Vq_inv(n) = prop_iq + int_iq(n) + (wL * I1d(n));
```

However, I noticed that the results obtained for iq_ref and Vq_inv in MATLAB are slightly different from the simulation results in Simulink. The values of these variables in MATLAB keep decreasing instead of remaining constant, as observed in the simulation.

**Steps Taken:**
Verified controller gains: The gains kpv, kiv, kpi, and kii have been double-checked and seem appropriate for the system.
Confirmed sampling time: The sampling time Ts used in the MATLAB code matches the actual sampling time used in the simulation.
Plotted  variables: I plotted P_1, Q_1, and theta1 to understand their behavior during simulation, but I couldn't identify the issue.
Request:
I am seeking guidance on identifying the source of the discrepancy and how to modify the MATLAB code to match the simulation results from Simulink accurately. Any insights, suggestions, or potential fixes would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your assistance.
Also, i can share .m and .slx file to understand this easily.

**Images:**
whole simulation:
[image]

from simulink to workspace:
[image]

result from simulink of iq_ref:
[image]

result from MATLAB program of iq_ref:
[image]

**Code:**

Va_1, Vb_1, Vc_1 and Ia_1, Ib_1, Ic_1 are imported from simulink in an array with sample time 1e-6 for 0.5 seconds
total samples = 500001

```
Ts=1e-06;
t = 0:Ts:0.5;
V1d=zeros(size(t));
V1q=zeros(size(t));
I1d=zeros(size(t));
I1q=zeros(size(t)); %  V1z=0.0;   I1z=0.0;
theta1=zeros(size(t));
Pf1new=zeros(size(t));  Pf1old=zeros(size(t));   Qf1new=zeros(size(t));   Qf1old=zeros(size(t));
P_1 = zeros(size(t));  Q_1 = zeros(size(t));

%f1error = [0.0 0.0];
%V1error; 
%V1out;
f1error = zeros(size(t));
error_vd= zeros(size(t));
error_vq= zeros(size(t));
error_id= zeros(size(t));
error_iq= zeros(size(t));
prop_vd=zeros(size(t));   prop_vq=zeros(size(t));   prop_id=zeros(size(t));   prop_iq=zeros(size(t));
int_vd = zeros(size(t));
int_vq = zeros(size(t));
int_id = zeros(size(t));
int_iq = zeros(size(t));
vanew=zeros(size(t));   vbnew=zeros(size(t));   vcnew=zeros(size(t));   vaold=zeros(size(t));   vbold=zeros(size(t));   vcold=zeros(size(t));
ianew=zeros(size(t));   ibnew=zeros(size(t));   icnew=zeros(size(t));   iaold=zeros(size(t));   ibold=zeros(size(t));   icold=zeros(size(t));
Vd_inv=zeros(size(t));   Vq_inv=zeros(size(t));   Vd_ref=zeros(size(t));   id_ref=zeros(size(t));   iq_ref=zeros(size(t));
m1=zeros(size(t));   n1=zeros(size(t));
V1d_off=zeros(size(t));   I1d_off=zeros(size(t));



wc=2*pi*50*9.94e-6; %0.0157; //314 rad/s*Cf
wL=2*pi*50*5.1e-3; %0.314; //314 rad/s*Lf

%//PI controller parameters
kpv=0.006245486195; %0.002
kiv=7.59150924004; %50
kpi=32.04424507; %2
kii=33740.7051; %50

%//Droop controller parameters
fnom = 50; %50.0
Vnom = 400; %10.0
Pbase = 10000*ones(size(t)); %500
%Qbase= 1*ones(size(t));
kf1=0.01; %0.01
kv1=0.05; %0.05

for n=2:500001
    vanew(n) = (Va_1(n)-vaold(1))+vaold(1);                  %  // Filter time constant is Ts*2pi*1000 for 1 kHz filter
    vaold(n) = vanew(n);
    
    vbnew(n) = (Vb_1(n)-vbold(1))+vbold(1);
    vbold(n) = vbnew(n);
    
    vcnew(n) = (Vc_1(n)-vcold(1))+vcold(1);
    vcold(n) = vcnew(n);
    
    ianew(n) = (Ia_1(n)-iaold(1))+iaold(1);
    iaold(n) = ianew(n);
    
    ibnew(n) = (Ib_1(n)-ibold(1))+ibold(1);
    ibold(n) = ibnew(n);
    
    icnew(n) = (Ic_1(n)-icold(1))+icold(1);
    icold(n) = icnew(n);
    
    V1d(n)=(2/3)*((sin(theta1(n)))*vanew(n)+(sin(theta1(n)-((2*pi)/3)))*vbnew(n)+(sin(theta1(n)+((2*pi)/3)))*vcnew(n));
    V1q(n)=(2/3)*((cos(theta1(n)))*vanew(n)+(cos(theta1(n)-((2*pi)/3)))*vbnew(n)+(cos(theta1(n)+((2*pi)/3)))*vcnew(n));
    I1d(n)=(2/3)*((sin(theta1(n)))*ianew(n)+(sin(theta1(n)-((2*pi)/3)))*ibnew(n)+(sin(theta1(n)+((2*pi)/3)))*icnew(n));
    I1q(n)=(2/3)*((cos(theta1(n)))*ianew(n)+(cos(theta1(n)-((2*pi)/3)))*ibnew(n)+(cos(theta1(n)+((2*pi)/3)))*icnew(n));
    
    
    
    P_1(n)=( V1d(n)*I1d(n) + V1q(n)*I1q(n) );
    Q_1(n)=( V1q(n)*I1d(n) - V1d(n)*I1q(n) );
    
    
    %/* Filter */
    Pf1new(n)=(P_1(n)-Pbase(n))+Pf1old(n);   %//Constant is Ts*wc=50e-6*31.41=0.0015705 0.0015705*
    Pf1old(n)=Pf1new(n);
    Qf1new(n)=(Q_1(n))+Qf1old(n);  % //Constant is Ts*wc=50e-6*31.41=0.0015705 0.0015705*
    Qf1old(n)=Qf1new(n);
    
    %//Droop control
    
    m1=kf1*(fnom/Pbase(n));
    n1=kv1*(Vnom/Pbase(n));
    
    %f1error(2) = (fnom-Pf1new(n)*m1) + f1error(1); %  0.0003142*         // Constant is 2*pi*Ts=2*3.14*50e-6=0.0003142
    %if(f1error(2)>6.28);
    %f1error(1) = f1error(2)-6.28; 
    %f1error(1) = f1error(2);
    %theta1(2)=f1error(1);
    %theta1(n+1)= (P_1(n)-Pbase)*theta1(1) + (2*pi*50*Ts); 
    theta1(n+1) = (2*pi*Ts)*(fnom-(Pf1new(n)*m1)) + theta1(n); %           // Constant is 2*pi*Ts=2*3.14*50e-6=0.0003142
    if theta1(n+1)>(2*pi)
        theta1(n+1) = theta1(n+1)-(2*pi);
        theta1(n+1) = theta1(n+1);
        theta1(n)=theta1(n+1);
    end
    
    Vd_ref(n) = (Vnom-(Qf1new(n)*n1));  %//Note that Vq_ref=0 by default
    Vq_ref(n)=0;
    % //PI control takes in Vd_ref and generates Vd_inv and Vq_inv
    
    % //PI controller for Vd
    error_vd(n)=((sqrt(2))*Vd_ref(n))-(V1d(n-1));
    prop_vd=kpv*error_vd(n);
    int_vd(n)=kiv*(Ts/2)*(error_vd(n)+error_vd(n-1))+int_vd(n-1);
    int_vd(n-1)=int_vd(n);
    error_vd(n-1)=error_vd(n);
    id_ref(n)=(prop_vd)+(int_vd(n))-(wc*V1q(n));         
    
    % //PI controller for Vq
    error_vq(n)=(Vq_ref(n))-(V1q(n-1));
    prop_vq=kpv*error_vq(n);
    int_vq(n)=kiv*(Ts/2)*(error_vq(n)+error_vq(n-1))+int_vq(n-1);
    int_vq(n-1)=int_vq(n);
    error_vq(n-1)=error_vq(n);
    iq_ref(n)=(prop_vq)+(int_vq(n))+(wc*V1d(n));
    
    %//PI controller for Id
    error_id(n)=id_ref(n)-(I1d(n-1));
    prop_id=kpi*error_id(n);
    int_id(n)=kii*(Ts/2)*(error_id(n)+error_id(n-1))+int_id(n-1);
    int_id(n-1)=int_id(n);
    error_id(n-1)=error_id(n);
    Vd_inv(n)=prop_id+int_id(n)-(wL*I1q(n));
    
    % //PI controller for Vq
    error_vq(n)=(Vq_ref(n))-(V1q(n-1));
    prop_vq=kpv*error_vq(n);
    int_vq(n)=kiv*(Ts/2)*(error_vq(n)+error_vq(n-1))+int_vq(n-1);
    int_vq(n-1)=int_vq(n);
    error_vq(n-1)=error_vq(n);
    iq_ref(n)=(prop_vq)+(int_vq(n))+(wc*V1d(n));
    
    
end
```